# How to find the number of orbits

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, symmetric-groups, permutations

In our lecture notes, i am confused on how to determined the number
of orbits with the given permutations in S4.
If i consider the permutation (12) . I can also rewrite it as cycle decomposi-
tion and that is (12)(3)(4). In practice we simply matters by not writing cycles
of length 1 and that makes me understand why (3)(4) is not added in the above.
In the example it says that the number of orbits is 3 and the 3 orbits are
listed: {{1,2},{3},{4}.I was thinking may be our lectrure counted the
number of sub-braces which is 3.
Now, if we consider the permutation (123) which can be further written in
cycle decomposition: (123)(4). It says the number of orbits is 4 and are listed :
{{1,2,3},{4}}. Now, while trying to use my assumption above, i could
not apply it in here. The number of sub-braces is 2 but the number
of orbits is 4. I am confused!!!
For the permutation (1234), The number of orbits is 1 which is listed:
{{1,2,3,4}} which agrees with my assumption above.
Can anyone show me the proper way of finding the number of orbits?

Comment: Do you understand what an orbit of a group action is?

Comment: $(123)(4)\in S_4$ acting on $\{1,2,3,4\}$ has two orbits, $\{1,2,3\}$ and $\{4\}$, not four. (If you were considering $(123)$ as an element of $S_6$, *then* it would have four orbits.)

Comment: ohh thankx anon!! that means there is an error in our lecture note!!

Comment: Yes, there is an error in your lecture notes. You are correct that the permutation $(123)$ has two orbits, which is, as you correctly observe, is the number of sub-braced elements in the set of orbits.